# changing image src for expand/collapse function (JQ or JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried several methods found on this site to get my script to change "+" and "-" expand/collapse button images, but I haven't yet found a suitable fix/method.

Currently, I am using plain JS as follows:

```
function swapimg(id) {
if(document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expand.png')
{document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expanded.png'}
else {document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expand.png'}
}
```

and the button:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="toggle_visibility('item1'); swapimg('phb');">
<img src="images/bullet_expand.png" border="0" style="padding-right: 5px;" id="phb" alt="">
</a>
```

The first click does change the image, but the second click does nothing. I have a feeling using "getElementById" might not be the standard call, so using JQuery is also an option I will consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of comparing you are assigning the value, you need `==` and not `=`

Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expand.png'
```

use

```
document.getElementById(id).src=='images/bullet_expand.png'
```

jQuery:

```
if(jQuery('#'+id).attr('src') == 'images/bullet_expand.png') {
   jQuery('#'+id).attr('src','images/bullet_expanded.png');
} else {
   jQuery('#'+id).attr('src','images/bullet_expand.png');
}
```

Javascript:

```
if(document.getElementById(id).src.indexOf('/images/bullet_expand.png') > 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expanded.png';
}
else {
    document.getElementById(id).src='images/bullet_expand.png';
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I changed the if to use double equal, but now it doesn't switch at all. Thanks for the clarification regarding == / =, I didn't realize JS  required this.

Comment: document.getElementById[].src will return full path of your image not the relative path, so instead of exact comparison you can also do contains check, updated my answer